# How do I log out of Stormpath ID Site with express-stormpath and stormpath-sdk-angularjs?

Tags: stormpath, express-stormpath

I have an express-stormpath application that uses Stormpath ID Site. It has this configuration:

```
app.use(stormpath.init(app, {
  web: {
    idSite: {
      enabled: true,
      uri: '/idSiteResult',
      nextUri: '/'
    },
    login: {
      enabled: true,
      uri: config.login
    },
    logout: {
      enabled: true,
      uri: config.logout
    },
    me: {
      expand: {
        customData: true,
        groups: true
      }
    }
  }
}));
```

Login works fine, but logout is giving me trouble.

First, I tried logging out with the stormpath-sdk-angularjs built-in endSession()

```
$auth.endSession();
```

But I was still logged in.

Digging into express-stormpath, it looks like [logout POST requires Accept type text/html for id-site logout](https://github.com/stormpath/express-stormpath/blob/5f97050fbfc30c44e6895250e3784ebbcf69ad15/lib/controllers/logout.js#L60-L78). In stormpath-sdk-angularjs, it looks like [endSession POST uses application/json](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-angularjs/blob/0f0529b9c203ba369118fa0ff542613845baa447/src/stormpath.auth.js#L184-L199).

So I tried logging out with $http.post

```
$http.post('/logout', null, {
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'text/html'
  }
});
```

But I get this error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.stormpath.com/sso/logout?jwtRequest=[...]. Redirect from 'https://api.stormpath.com/sso/logout?jwtRequest=[...]' to 'http://localhost:9000/idSiteResult?jwtResponse=[...]' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access.

How do I log out of Stormpath ID Site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work at Stormpath. ID Site requires that you actually redirect the end user to ID Site. I'm not sure why `endSession()` isn't working, but I'll reach out to our JS team to see if there might be a bug there.

In the meantime, you can use this code (or the equivalent in Angular-specific primitives) to accomplish a logout:

```js
var form = document.createElement('form');
form.method = "POST";
form.action = "/logout";
form.submit();
```

Comment: If you use csurf on your express server, also make sure to send the XSRF-TOKEN (and not the _csrf cookie) with the form.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a CORS issue. I believe you need to add at least;

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://api.stormpath.com
```

To the response headers from your server.